# Write Random Files to HDFS - PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have not seen any examples for how to do this.  I'm on PySpark 2.0 in a python 3  environment.  I have random data, binary data, .jpg data, random strings.  I just need to put the data back down to the underlying storage.

For example:

```
import os
with open(os.path.join(base_dir, 'RF_model.txt'), "w") as file1:
    toFile = raw_input(RF_model.toDebugString())
    file1.write(toFile)
```

(The above does not work)

Thanks!

EDIT -------------- what RF_model.toDebugString() outputs ----

```
 Tree 0:
    If (feature 0 <= 64.0)
     If (feature 2 <= 212.0)
      If (feature 3 <= 0.0)
       If (feature 2 <= 154.0)
        Predict: 1.0
       Else (feature 2 > 154.0)
        Predict: 1.0
      Else (feature 3 > 0.0)
       If (feature 2 <= 147.0)
        Predict: 0.0
       Else (feature 2 > 147.0)
        Predict: 0.0
     Else (feature 2 > 212.0)
      If (feature 2 <= 375.0)
       If (feature 3 <= 0.0)
        Predict: 0.0
       Else (feature 3 > 0.0)
        Predict: 0.0
      Else (feature 2 > 375.0)
       If (feature 0 <= 22.0)
        Predict: 0.0
       Else (feature 0 > 22.0)
        Predict: 0.0
    Else (feature 0 > 64.0)
     If (feature 2 <= 239.0)
      If (feature 3 <= 0.0)
       If (feature 2 <= 200.0)
        Predict: 0.0
       Else (feature 2 > 200.0)
        Predict: 0.0
      Else (feature 3 > 0.0)
       If (feature 2 <= 124.0)
        Predict: 0.0
       Else (feature 2 > 124.0)
        Predict: 0.0
     Else (feature 2 > 239.0)
      If (feature 2 <= 375.0)
       If (feature 1 <= 67.0)
        Predict: 0.0
       Else (feature 1 > 67.0)
        Predict: 0.0
      Else (feature 2 > 375.0)
       If (feature 1 <= 63.0)
        Predict: 0.0
       Else (feature 1 > 63.0)
        Predict: 0.0
  Tree 1:
    If (feature 0 <= 64.0)
     If (feature 2 <= 224.0)
      If (feature 3 <= 0.0)
       If (feature 2 <= 170.0)
        Predict: 1.0
       Else (feature 2 > 170.0)
        Predict: 1.0
      Else (feature 3 > 0.0)
       If (feature 2 <= 158.0)
        Predict: 0.0
       Else (feature 2 > 158.0)
        Predict: 0.0
     Else (feature 2 > 224.0)
      If (feature 2 <= 375.0)
       If (feature 3 <= 0.0)
        Predict: 0.0
       Else (feature 3 > 0.0)
        Predict: 0.0
```

Comment: what `toFile = raw_input(RF_model.toDebugString())` this suppose to achive?  `.toDebugString()` on rdd returns description of this RDD (RF_model) and its recursive dependencies for debugging.

Comment: it is simply a string; I'll add it into the above.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I am right when I assume that you want to write output of `.toDebugString()` to text file,

In pyspark you can save any parallelize data as text file using `.saveAsTextFile` -

```
# imp step : first parallelize data that you need to save
rdd = sc.parallelize([str(RF_Model.toDebugString())])

# then save as text file , using below if underline storage is HDFS
rdd.saveAsTextFile('hdfs://'+base_dir+"/RF_model.txt")
```

or if you just want to save it in local file system -

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile("file:///"+base_dir+"/RF_model.txt")
```

Comment: What about if the file is not text? For example, if I have a file that cannot be loaded into an RDD/DF and I need to get it to S3, how would I do that? Would the best option be to use something like boto?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the underlying java classes available through the SparkSession (tested in Spark 3.1, but should also work for Spark 2).

If the hdfs configuration is correctly set up in your current Spark instance, you can do the following:

```
# get java classes
Path = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

# create FileSystem and Path objects
hadoopConfiguration = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopFs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration)
filePath = Path('/path/to/file')

# create datastream and write out file
dataStream = hadoopFs.create(filePath)
dataStream.write('text I want to write'.encode('utf-8'))
dataStream.close()
```

Otherwise you can manually specify the hdfs ip and port:

```
# get java classes
Path = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
URI = spark.sparkContext._jvm.java.net.URI
Configuration = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

# create FileSystem and Path objects
hdfsUri = URI('hdfs://hdfs-ip:port')
hadoopFs = FileSystem.get(hdfsUri, Configuration())
filePath = Path('/path/to/file')
```

The `dataStream.write()` method takes in bytes so can be used to write arbitrary binary data, or you can find methods that take other types [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataOutputStream.html).